# Why git diff shows identical files as modified?

Tags: git, diff

The files have the same hash, but git thinks the file has been modified on every single line except the last line. This is from a rsync -azP clone of git working directory. I did this to move a svn to git (git svn fetch, then git svn rebase) repository to another host.

the host where the git repository was on => Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, git 2.6.4
rsync destination CentOS 7.2.1511 (Core), git 1.8.3.1

in both files lines end in ^M$

I suspect this is caused by git config or git bug.

```
git diff src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj
diff --git a/src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj b/src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj
index e6491ab..8b7ec22 100644
--- a/src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj
+++ b/src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj
@@ -1,69 +1,69 @@
-<U+FEFF><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
-  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
-    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
-      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
-      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
-    </ProjectConfiguration>
-    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
-      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
-      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
-    </ProjectConfiguration>
-  </ItemGroup>
-  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
-    <ProjectGuid>{8598C2C8-34C4-47A1-99B0-7C295A890615}</ProjectGuid>
-    <RootNamespace>msvc-generate</RootNamespace>
-    <Keyword>MakeFileProj</Keyword>
-  </PropertyGroup>
-  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
-  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
-    <ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>
-  </PropertyGroup>
-  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
-    <ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>
-  </PropertyGroup>
-  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
-  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
-  </ImportGroup>
-  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
-    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')
-  </ImportGroup>
-  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
-    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')
-  </ImportGroup>
-  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
-  <PropertyGroup>
-    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
-    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
-    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
-    <NMakeBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak all</NMakeBuildCommandLine>
-    <NMakeReBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean all</NMakeReBuildCommandLine>
-    <NMakeCleanCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean</NMakeCleanCommandLine>
-    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">config-msvc-version.h</NMakeOutput>
-    <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">WIN32;_DEBUG;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakePre
-    <NMakeIncludeSearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)</NMakeIncludeSearchPath>
-    <NMakeForcedIncludes Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedIncludes)</NMakeForcedIncludes>
-    <NMakeAssemblySearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeAssemblySearchPath)</NMakeAssemblySearchPath>
-    <NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies)</NMakeForcedUsingAssemblie
-    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
-    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
-    <NMakeBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak all</NMakeBuildCommandLine>
-    <NMakeReBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean all</NMakeReBuildCommandLine>
-    <NMakeCleanCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean</NMakeCleanCommandLine>
-    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">config-msvc-version.h</NMakeOutput>
-    <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">WIN32;NDEBUG;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakeP
-    <NMakeIncludeSearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)</NMakeIncludeSearchPath>
-    <NMakeForcedIncludes Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedIncludes)</NMakeForcedIncludes>
-    <NMakeAssemblySearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeAssemblySearchPath)</NMakeAssemblySearchPath>
-    <NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies)</NMakeForcedUsingAssembl
-  </PropertyGroup>
-  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
-  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
-  <ItemGroup>
-    <None Include="Makefile.mak" />
-    <None Include="msc-generate.js" />
-  </ItemGroup>
-  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
-  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
-  </ImportGroup>
+<U+FEFF><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
+<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
+  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
+    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
+      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
+      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
+    </ProjectConfiguration>
+    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
+      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
+      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
+    </ProjectConfiguration>
+  </ItemGroup>
+  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
+    <ProjectGuid>{8598C2C8-34C4-47A1-99B0-7C295A890615}</ProjectGuid>
+    <RootNamespace>msvc-generate</RootNamespace>
+    <Keyword>MakeFileProj</Keyword>
+  </PropertyGroup>
+  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
+  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
+    <ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>
+  </PropertyGroup>
+  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
+    <ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>
+  </PropertyGroup>
+  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
+  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
+  </ImportGroup>
+  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
+    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')
+  </ImportGroup>
+  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
+    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')
+  </ImportGroup>
+  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
+  <PropertyGroup>
+    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
+    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
+    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
+    <NMakeBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak all</NMakeBuildCommandLine>
+    <NMakeReBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean all</NMakeReBuildCommandLine>
+    <NMakeCleanCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean</NMakeCleanCommandLine>
+    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">config-msvc-version.h</NMakeOutput>
+    <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">WIN32;_DEBUG;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakePre
+    <NMakeIncludeSearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)</NMakeIncludeSearchPath>
+    <NMakeForcedIncludes Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedIncludes)</NMakeForcedIncludes>
+    <NMakeAssemblySearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeAssemblySearchPath)</NMakeAssemblySearchPath>
+    <NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies)</NMakeForcedUsingAssemblie
+    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
+    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
+    <NMakeBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak all</NMakeBuildCommandLine>
+    <NMakeReBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean all</NMakeReBuildCommandLine>
+    <NMakeCleanCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean</NMakeCleanCommandLine>
+    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">config-msvc-version.h</NMakeOutput>
+    <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">WIN32;NDEBUG;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakeP
+    <NMakeIncludeSearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)</NMakeIncludeSearchPath>
+    <NMakeForcedIncludes Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedIncludes)</NMakeForcedIncludes>
+    <NMakeAssemblySearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeAssemblySearchPath)</NMakeAssemblySearchPath>
+    <NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies)</NMakeForcedUsingAssembl
+  </PropertyGroup>
+  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
+  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
+  <ItemGroup>
+    <None Include="Makefile.mak" />
+    <None Include="msc-generate.js" />
+  </ItemGroup>
+  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
+  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
+  </ImportGroup>
 </Project>
\ No newline at end of file
```

Edit1:

od -t x1 output from both files are exactly the same

Encoding, line break permissions are exactly the same too

`src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj: XML  document, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators`

Edit2

Both files are the same in cat -A, how is this related to autocrlf?

```
$ cat -A src/router/openvpn/build/msvc/msvc-generate/msvc-generate.vcxproj
M-oM-;M-?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>^M$
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">^M$
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">^M$
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">^M$
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>^M$
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>^M$
    </ProjectConfiguration>^M$
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">^M$
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>^M$
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>^M$
    </ProjectConfiguration>^M$
  </ItemGroup>^M$
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">^M$
    <ProjectGuid>{8598C2C8-34C4-47A1-99B0-7C295A890615}</ProjectGuid>^M$
    <RootNamespace>msvc-generate</RootNamespace>^M$
    <Keyword>MakeFileProj</Keyword>^M$
  </PropertyGroup>^M$
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />^M$
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">^M$
    <ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>^M$
  </PropertyGroup>^M$
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">^M$
    <ConfigurationType>Makefile</ConfigurationType>^M$
  </PropertyGroup>^M$
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />^M$
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">^M$
  </ImportGroup>^M$
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">^M$
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />^M$
  </ImportGroup>^M$
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">^M$
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />^M$
  </ImportGroup>^M$
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />^M$
  <PropertyGroup>^M$
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion>^M$
    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</OutDir>^M$
    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</IntDir>^M$
    <NMakeBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak all</NMakeBuildCommandLine>^M$
    <NMakeReBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean all</NMakeReBuildCommandLine>^M$
    <NMakeCleanCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean</NMakeCleanCommandLine>^M$
    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">config-msvc-version.h</NMakeOutput>^M$
    <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">WIN32;_DEBUG;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakePreprocessorDefinitions>^M$
    <NMakeIncludeSearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)</NMakeIncludeSearchPath>^M$
    <NMakeForcedIncludes Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedIncludes)</NMakeForcedIncludes>^M$
    <NMakeAssemblySearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeAssemblySearchPath)</NMakeAssemblySearchPath>^M$
    <NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies)</NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies>^M$
    <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</OutDir>^M$
    <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)\</IntDir>^M$
    <NMakeBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak all</NMakeBuildCommandLine>^M$
    <NMakeReBuildCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean all</NMakeReBuildCommandLine>^M$
    <NMakeCleanCommandLine Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">nmake -f Makefile.mak clean</NMakeCleanCommandLine>^M$
    <NMakeOutput Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">config-msvc-version.h</NMakeOutput>^M$
    <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">WIN32;NDEBUG;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakePreprocessorDefinitions>^M$
    <NMakeIncludeSearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)</NMakeIncludeSearchPath>^M$
    <NMakeForcedIncludes Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedIncludes)</NMakeForcedIncludes>^M$
    <NMakeAssemblySearchPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeAssemblySearchPath)</NMakeAssemblySearchPath>^M$
    <NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies)</NMakeForcedUsingAssemblies>^M$
  </PropertyGroup>^M$
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>^M$
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>^M$
  <ItemGroup>^M$
    <None Include="Makefile.mak" />^M$
    <None Include="msc-generate.js" />^M$
  </ItemGroup>^M$
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />^M$
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">^M$
  </ImportGroup>^M$
</Project>
```

Comment: What if you use another diff utility? Are you sure there is no extra spaces?

Comment: You should write more details of  "This is from a rsync clone of git working directory."

Comment: It's a CR/LF problem

Comment: use `od -t x1` on both files and compare the bytes. probably a text encoding thing or line feed issue.

Comment: Try first `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, then clone again and see if the issue persists

Comment: Isn't false the default config?

Comment: The point you're missing is that git *fiddles* with line endings based on your `autocrlf` setting. I'm not sure *exactly* what's happening (more details of the actual commands you've run would help), but it's definitely autocrlf that's causing the problem.

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf no false is not the default config. Can you try it? Clone again? And see if the issue persists?

Comment: @VonC it sounds like they didn't clone at all, but rsync'd an existing repo.

Comment: On the destination I set `git config --global core.autocrlf input` then did `git reset --hard`, now the working directory is clean. The file is still exactly the same. So git didn't modify EoL, just "think" differently with autocrlf config?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `core.autocrlf`.

#### `core.autocrlf = true`

> Text files checked-out from the repository that have only `LF` EOL characters are normalized to `CRLF` in your working tree; files that contain `CRLF` in the repository will not be touched
>
> Text files that have only `LF` EOL characters in the repository, are  normalized from `CRLF` to `LF` when committed back to the repository. Files that contain `CRLF` in the repository will be committed untouched.

#### `core.autocrlf = input`

> Text files checked-out from the repository will keep original EOL characters in your working tree.
>
> Text files in your working tree with `CRLF` EOL characters are normalized to `LF` when committed back to the repository.

#### `core.autocrlf = false`

> `core.eol` dictates EOL characters in the text files of your working tree.
>
> `core.eol = native` by default, which means Windows EOLs are `CRLF` and Unix-based OS are `LF` in working trees.

Comment: I am just creating a git mirror of a svn repository without any modification, what autocrlf should I use in this case?

Comment: You simply set it globally on your machine. depend on the OS Win/unix/Mac etc

Comment: usually you should use: `git config --global core.autocrlf false`